# Executar um script automaticamente - sem o uso de CRON

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, listener

Eu normalmente agendo um script que deve ser executado de tempos em tempos (como atualizador de status de pedido, por exemplo) utilizando o CRON do Linux. (Não faço idéia como se faz isso em hospedagens Windows)

Porém, reparei que o Wordpress parece fazer isso sem o uso de CRON, pois ele atualiza sozinho automaticamente quando o owner de sua instalação tem o acesso para tanto. Porém não encontrei em seu código como ele faz isso.

Detalhe, essa atualização funciona independente do SO utilizado (mesmo em windows).

Como, então, criar um listener que se execute de maneira automática?

**Aplicação:** Atualizador automático do app, atualizador de status de pedido, criador de backups de arquivos, entre outros.

Comment: o que o wp faz é quando alguem acessa a aplicação ele verifica o agendamento e executa o que é necessário, assim como o cron em windows temos o agendador de tarefas que pode ser utilizado para isto.

Comment: Obrigado @Otto pela resposta. Eu imaginei que fosse algo assim, mas note que o wordpress se atualiza mesmo quando seu admin não não é acessado. Ou ele executa o listener tb quando o blog é acessado? Isso não impactaria no desempenho?

Comment: O listner é quando o blog é acessado, vou converter meu comentario em resposta, ja que te ajudou

Comment: você quer fazer isso dentro do wordpress?

Comment: Não @CaioFelipePereira. Usei o WP como exemplo. Tenho meus próprios scripts PHP. Mas, aparentemente, o que ele faz é executar o script programado quando alguem acessa o blog. Pelo menos foi o que o Otto informou. Vamos ver se alguem descobre um método diferente.

Comment: @Szag-Ot, é exatamente isso que ele faz mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que o wp faz é quando alguem acessa a aplicação ele verifica o agendamento e executa o que é necessário, assim como o cron em windows temos o agendador de tarefas que pode ser utilizado para isto.

O listner é quando o blog é acessado, pois tenho alguns blogs com agendamento semanal e não os acesso diariamente, porém seus posts estão sempre sendo feitos.